# GraphQL + Mongoose - When returning an FindOneAndUpdate my inc value is multiple times more than it should be

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am using graphQL and mongoose to query my database.

My intention is to increment a value by 1 for a set record.

```
Mutation: {
    cardcompared (root, {name}, context, info) {
      console.log('mutation');
      return Card.findOneAndUpdate({name: name}, {$inc : {comparisons: 1}}, {new: true}, function(err, card) {
        console.log(card.comparisons);
      })
}
```

For some reason when I return the value the return seems to cause my increment value to be randomly 1, 2 or 3 when using `{$inc : {comparisons: 1}}`.

but the following code works as expected

```
Mutation: {
    cardcompared (root, {name}, context, info) {
      console.log('mutation');
      Card.findOneAndUpdate({name: name}, {$inc : {comparisons: 1}}, {new: true}, function(err, card) {
        console.log(card.comparisons);
      })
}
```

Above code $inc the value by 1 everytime.

I am unsure why this is happening.

Comment: due to closure property At first example returning function is executing more than once so value is incrementing very high than 1.

Comment: in step 2 you are not returning function so it is executing only one time

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures